# Connecting to a new WiFi network

Tags: network, wifi, ios

In iOS 10, is there an easy way to connect to a new WiFi network if automatic connect is turned off? I turned that off because it's way too annoying.

So right now, connecting is a multi-step process going through the Settings app. Am I missing a hidden way to do that from the start screen.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a new wifi network, the only way to connect (not including any 3rd-party app) is to go thru `Settings -> Wi-Fi`.

If you're open to 3rd-party solutions, perhaps you can [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/286577/edit) your question to add that?